# Can you show me how to evaluate this integral using residue theorem? I keep getting the wrong answer

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have been looking around and found similar problems but I think I'm making a mistake specific to this problem.  For some reason I keep finding $0$ using Residue Theorem instead of what I am suppose to find

show that
$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a+b\cos{(\theta})}d\theta = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} $

using $z=e^{i\theta}\rightarrow d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$, and rewriting $cos(\theta)=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$

I changed the original integral to
$\oint\frac{-2i}{bz^2+2az+b}dz$

Then I found the zeros of the polynomial in the denominator to be

$z_1=\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$, $z_2=\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}$

Then the integral becomes $\oint\frac{-2i}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}dz$ and we have simple poles at $z_1,z_2$ so I start using the Residue Theorem.

=$2\pi i\left[Res(f(z),z_1)+Res(f(z),z_2)\right]$

=$2\pi i\left[\lim\limits_{z\to z_1}(z-z_1)\frac{-2i}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}+\lim\limits_{z\to z_2}(z-z_2)\frac{-2i}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\right]$

=$2\pi i\left[\lim\limits_{z\to z_1}\frac{-2i}{(z-z_2)}+\lim\limits_{z\to z_2}\frac{-2i}{(z-z_1)}\right]$

=$4\pi\left[\frac{1}{z_1-z_2}+\frac{1}{z_2-z_1}\right]$, when plugging in the values for $z_1,z_2$ I find

=$0\neq \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$

EDIT:The original problem is stated like this

Show that

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a+b\cos{(\theta)}}d\theta=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$

Hint: Use the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? How do you know that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are both inside the contour?

Comment: @geetha290krm i updated the question to show the original problem I was given.  Does that help?  How would I go about checking if one of the roots is not in the contour? a and b are just constants. If its not in the contour then I need to do a partial frac decomp and one of the integrals is just zero, but its not immediately clear how I would check that with a and b not given so I assume they are, as simple poles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the residues only of poles lying **inside the contour.** Here the contour is the unit circle and the quadratic denominator, whose coefficients read the same fowards and backwards, must have its roots as reciprocals of one another. Therefore just one pole is inside the unit circle (for $|a|>|b|$, which is required for the integral to converge).

You need to identify the correct pole inside the contour and take its residue alone, which will be nonzero. For example, with $a$ and $b$ both positive and $a>b$, you find that $z_2<-1$ (the numerator there is less than $-b$), so the reciprocal, $z_1$, lies between $0$ and $-1$ — so the latter is the residue inside the unit circle.

You may want to check whether there is an assumption that $a$ is positive. That is needed for the given answer. A negative value of $a$ would give a negative instead of positive value for the definite integral.

Comment: What do you mean "whose coefficients read the same forwards and backwards".  by roots as reciprocals do you mean $z_1=\frac{1}{z_2}$ or do you mean conjugates of one another i.e. $z_1=\overline{z_2}$?

Comment: I just computed with  $z_1$ inside the contour and $z_2$ outside the contour and it gave the correct answer.  However, I'm still confused with how to check this.  Can you show me in your post?  and I'll checkmark it.  thanks!

Comment: are we assuming $|a|>|b|$ because of the RHS of the equation with $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt  {a^2-b^2}}$ implying that it stays in $\mathbb{R}$ thus  making $a^2>b^2$? because this would make my $z_2$ outside of the unit circle, giving the desired result with Residue about $z_1$

Comment: The roots are alwaysp reciprocals whenever the coefficients read the same forwards and backwards. Since real numbers can be reciprocals of each other, the roots might not be conjugates.

Comment: I don't think the values of a,b are particularly important here because if I take $\lim\limits_{z\to z_1}(z-z_1)\frac{-2i}{bz^2+2az+b}$ I get $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$.  However, if I do $\lim\limits_{z\to z_1}(z-z_1)\frac{-2i}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}$ I get $\frac{2\pi b}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$.  Am I incorrect using the second form?

Comment: I'm using Maple symbolic environment to check my work.  the expression $\frac{1}{z_1-z_2} = \frac{b}{2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$.  but if I do it using polynomial form it works

Comment: Ecause $bz^2+2az+b=\color{blue}{b}(z-z_1)(z-z_2)$. Remember the constant factor when you make the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Thats what I was missing, that factor of "b".  Thank you.

Comment: @EvanHowington Short explanation for the statement about roots: if $z\neq 0$ is a root of $a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n=0$ then $\frac1z$ is a root of $a_0+\frac{a_1}x+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{x^n}=0$; multiplying this by $x^n$ we see that $\frac1z$ is a root of the 'reverse' polynomial $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n$. In this case, since the reverse polynomial is the same as the original one, then if $z$ is a root $\frac1z$ also must be one.

Comment: Thanks @StevenStadnicki .  Do you think that is what Oscar was referring to above?

Comment: I think that's exactly it, yes.

Comment: I agree, Steven has explained the reciprocal roots well. (I was hoping tge abswer would not have needed this digression.)